# Yajra DataTable Get Row Index Inside addColumn Method

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable

I want to know the first and last row in the table in addColumn for the logic inside it like using the blade template `$loop->first` or `$loop->iteration`.

The code:

```
return DataTables::eloquent(HomeBanner::query())
    ->addColumn('sort', function($row) {
        if ($row->first) {
            'first'
        } elseif ($row->last) {
            'last'
        } else {
            'middle'
        }
    })
    ->toJson();
```

Comment: `->addIndexColumn()` can handle `loop iteration`

Comment: but how I can get the index inside addColumn?

Comment: DT_RowIndex if you use ->addIndexColumn()

Comment: I tried `->addColumn('sort', function($row) { dd($row->DT_RowIndex) ...` get a null instead

Comment: if you want to check in this you have to check in index primary keys $row->id

Comment: ah okay, the problem is the first id isn't always 1 so I need another logic to get the first row

Comment: Dont find any builtin function in yajrabox, but I think it can be possible by elequent `first()`, then check if else with `$row`

Comment: @sta this is not very helpful  - would you mind providing an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the first and last element by parameter and compare it inside addColumn

```
$data = Language::where('is_published', 1)->orderBy('position', 'ASC');
$first = Language::where('is_published', 1)->orderBy('position', 'ASC')->first();
$last = Language::where('is_published', 1)->orderBy('position', 'DESC')->first();
        return Datatables::of($data)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('actions', function ($row) use ($first, $last) {
                if ($row == $first) {
                    $info = 'first';
                }elseif($row == $last){
                    $info = 'last';
                }else{
                    $info = 'middle';
                }
                return $info;
            })
            ->rawColumns(['actions'])
            ->make(true);
```

Comment: This can work but needs a more complex query if the user using a filter or order and that code didn't catch the last row in one page when the table uses pagination, that's why I hope yajrabox has a built-in for knowing the row index inside addColumn method.